# two boxes with fix width one with center letter

Tags: tabularx

I have the following command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, vmargin={2.5cm,1.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}  

\newcounter{som}
\newcounter{sub}[som]
\definecolor{Som}{RGB}{240,185,134} 
\newcommand{\opg}[2]{%
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{1.0cm} X @{}}
    \parbox[t]{0.35cm}{
      \begin{tabularx}{0.5cm}{@{} !{\color{white}\vrule} c !{\color{white}\vrule} >{\columncolor{Som}}c X @{}}
        \arrayrulecolor{white}\cline{1-1}
          \makebox[0.1cm]{\ }  & 
          \makebox[0.1cm]{\color{white}\textbf{\arabic{som}}} \cr
          \arrayrulecolor{white}\cline{1-1}  \arrayrulecolor{Som}\cline{2-2}
      \end{tabularx}} &
  #2
  \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document} 

\opg{O}{bla bla bla ....}

\end{document}
```

Now should be the line start with a boxed letter (`#1`) and a number (given by `som`), after 1cm the bla bla bla text should come.

It does, but the letter and the number are not aligned in the center of the boxes.

The boxes should be fixed width so when `som` becomes 10, it will be the same box width.

I tried many things but the are not nice and do not work. Please help.

[image]

Comment: The `parbox` has width `0.35cm`, but the inner `tabularx` has width `0.5cm`. Also, there are white rules on white background. Or, there is an `\makebox` with an invisible space. Please, simplify the example and explain, what the result should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, what the result should be. The following example addresses following issues:

- Background is added to the table. Then the white lines can be seen.
- The boxes with the white frame are done with `\fcolorbox`. The width for the box contents is set to the width of `10`, the contents is horizontally centered. The height and depth of the two touching boxes are the same.
- The inner table is avoided and the text of the boxes and the first line of the following column are now vertically aligned at the baseline.

Example file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, vmargin={2.5cm,1.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{som}
\newcounter{sub}[som]
\definecolor{Som}{RGB}{240,185,134}

\newdimen\opgBoxWidth
\newcommand{\opg}[2]{%
  \par
  \noindent
  \settowidth\opgBoxWidth{10}%
  \colorbox{black!10!white}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{@{} l X @{}}%
      \bfseries
      \fcolorbox{white}{Som}{%
        \color{white}%
        \makebox[\opgBoxWidth]{\vphantom{\thesom}#1}%
      }%
      \kern-\fboxrule
      \fcolorbox{white}{Som}{%
        \color{white}%
        \makebox[\opgBoxWidth]{\vphantom{#1}\thesom}%
      }%
      &%
      #2%
    \end{tabularx}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\opg{O}{bla bla bla \dots}

\setcounter{som}{10}
\opg{A}{bla bla bla \dots}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

---

## Second version

Still, the horizontal placement of the number is quite unclear. The width of the wide letter `M` is used as width for the letter box.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, vmargin={2.5cm,1.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{som}
\newcounter{sub}[som]
\definecolor{Som}{RGB}{240,185,134}

\newdimen\opgBoxLetterWidth
\newdimen\opgBoxNumberWidth
\newcommand{\opg}[2]{%
  \par
  \noindent
  \settowidth\opgBoxLetterWidth{\bfseries M}%
  \settowidth\opgBoxNumberWidth{\bfseries 10}%
  \colorbox{black!10!white}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{
      @{}
      l
      >{\centering}p{\opgBoxNumberWidth}
      @{\kern1cm}
      X
      @{}
    }%
      \bfseries
      \fcolorbox{Som}{white}{%
        \color{Som}%
        \makebox[\opgBoxNumberWidth]{\vphantom{\thesom}#1}%
      }%
      &
      \bfseries
      \thesom
      &%
      #2%
    \end{tabularx}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\opg{O}{bla bla bla \dots}

\setcounter{som}{10}
\opg{A}{bla bla bla \dots}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result second version]

---

## Third version

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, vmargin={2.5cm,1.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{som}
\newcounter{sub}[som]
\definecolor{Som}{RGB}{240,185,134}

\newdimen\opgBoxWidth
\newcommand{\opg}[2]{%
  \par
  \noindent
  \settowidth\opgBoxWidth{\bfseries 10}%
  \colorbox{black!10!white}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{
      @{}
      l
      @{\kern1cm}
      X
      @{}
    }%
      \bfseries
      \fcolorbox{Som}{white}{%
        \color{Som}%
        \makebox[\opgBoxWidth]{\vphantom{\thesom}#1}%
      }%
      \kern-\fboxrule
      \advance\fboxsep\fboxrule
      \colorbox{Som}{%
        \color{white}%
        \makebox[\opgBoxWidth]{\vphantom{#1}\thesom}%
      }%
      &%
      #2%
    \end{tabularx}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\opg{O}{bla bla bla \dots}

\setcounter{som}{10}
\opg{A}{bla bla bla \dots}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result third version]

Comment: But the first box should be framed with the color Som, the second should not have a frame (so I made it the same color of the background so the boxes are the same hight)

Comment: Also schould the Letter apear in the color Som. With white background and a frame of the color Som.

Comment: And bla bla bla should start after 1cm.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks, I put an example in the text above.

Comment: Thanks, perfect.
Could you tell me something you did, I want to learn.
F.E.
{\vphantom{\thesom}
\kern-\fboxrule
\advance\fboxsep\fboxrule
\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax